# Not able to push in Github

Tags: git, github

I was pushing my code to a new repository i made and while pushing i got the error:

```
    git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to 
Kiranchavan14/Portfolio.git denied to 
KiranChavan11.
fatal: unable to access
```

`'https://github.com/Kiranchavan14/Portfolio.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I dont know much about GitHub and came across this problem.

when i do `git remote -v`

i Get

```
origin  https://github.com/Kiranchavan14/Portfolio.git (fetch)
origin  
https://github.com/Kiranchavan14/Portfolio.git (push)
```

How can i change\remove this and add a new origin master.

Maybe I sound funny. But Sorry i dont know much about github.

Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the repository from settings and create a new repository. [Follow](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/) instructions

Comment: Ya i deleted the repo as you said but now i get a error saying "Repository Not Found"

Comment: how do you clone the repository? I followed the instructions and cloned the repository to my laptop and then pushed files without any issues.

Comment: I dont know Please Help